# Parse JSON with an Optional in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

```
Optional({"session":{"_id":"574fe96fa28f9aaadb000034","application_id":41262,"created_at":"2016-06-02T08:08:15Z","device_id":0,"nonce":21576,"token":"5b04f409c06ecf24ad2d9479a1ef7ef78916f864","ts":1464854895,"updated_at":"2016-06-02T08:08:15Z","user_id":0,"id":7274}})
```

I need to parse and save token from the above dictionary (in Swift)

My request goes like this :

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let dict = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(dict)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

Need to parse dict

Comment: And we need to see some effort...

Comment: So.. what have you tried so far? This site is not for free-code hand outs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 4:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

guard let data = data, error == nil else {
    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
    return
}
let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
if let data = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {

    if let success = data["success"] as? Int {

        if success == 1 {

            self.dataArray = data["results"] as! Array

            label.text = self.dataArray[row]["id"] as? String

        // parse in similar fashion

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsing/mapping can be a pain and time consuming.

I just happen to have made a tool for it :

[Jenerator](https://github.com/romainmenke/Jenerator)

[Download from here](https://github.com/romainmenke/Jenerator/releases/tag/0.12) and move to /usr/local/bin/

It is a little command line tool written in Swift to generate a Swift model based on a JSON. If I passed it your JSON it gave me back this :

```
import Foundation

struct SOSession {

    var created_at : String
    var _id : String
    var id : Int
    var device_id : Int
    var token : String
    var updated_at : String
    var nonce : Int
    var user_id : Int
    var ts : Int
    var application_id : Int

    init(data:[String:AnyObject]) {
        self.created_at = (data["created_at"] as? String) ?? ""
        self._id = (data["_id"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.id = (data["id"] as? Int) ?? 0
        self.device_id = (data["device_id"] as? Int) ?? 0
        self.token = (data["token"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.updated_at = (data["updated_at"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.nonce = (data["nonce"] as? Int) ?? 0
        self.user_id = (data["user_id"] as? Int) ?? 0
        self.ts = (data["ts"] as? Int) ?? 0
        self.application_id = (data["application_id"] as? Int) ?? 0
    }

    static func fromSource(urlString : String) -> SOSession? {
        guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            if let outerDict = json as? [String:AnyObject], let dict = outerDict["session"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                return SOSession(data: dict)
            }
        } catch {}
        return nil
    }
}
```

Getting the Token then becomes as simple as this :

```
let myToken = SOSession.fromSource("someUrl")?.token
```

To use Jenerator I saved your JSON in a file on my desktop and ran in terminal :

```
jenerator "$HOME/Desktop/so-1.json" StackOverflowQuestion1 SO

jenerator "path-to-file-with-json" save-file-name class-prefix
```

You can now copy the generator code to your project.